# Truffle init returns cannot find module

Tags: node.js, truffle

After installing nodejs, I created a directory, installed truffle, but after typing the command `truffle init` it returns this error. I've tried everything, but this doesn't go away. I've reinstalled yet it's the same. How do I fix this?

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lawrence david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Did you use ``npm install truffle`` ?

Comment: Yes. I used "npm install truffle -g" since without "-g" runs it only locally. Pls help me fix this. I've been battling this issue for almost a week now

Answer (score 3):

I've solved the issue.
All you need to do is to run "npm install -g truffle@5.4.29"
This will install an older version of truffle. Turns out the issue is with "npm install -g truffle" since it installs the latest version, and the latest version is currently having glitches.

Just run "npm install -g truffle@5.4.29" or an older version of truffle and your issue will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

Delete node_modules and run npm install again

Comment: Hi, i just did what you said. I deleted node_modules, ran "npm install" then ran "npm install -g truffle" and finally "truffle init" command again. Yet, same error. Pls i'm still looking for a fix, can someone help me out

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.